# WSO2 API Manager Client Credentials renew token

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to renew the token generated through API Manager.

The curl statement for generate token is:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic TDQ0SktDZm5DcVVDSVBjdGYwVDIyRWwwUGY4YT
o2d19NQm9xYnBFXzRLNHR0Wkc0NXhxd0NMTDRh , Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://10.108.106.214:8250/token
```

The response is

```
"scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1094,"access_token":"6d1d0f8afbd147d24bcd42bbc5361a1"
```

Based on the documentation it is supposed to generate a retoken which is not being genarated. What am I missing?

Also when I pass the grant_type as refresh_token. I get a invalid grant error.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic TDQ0SktDZm5DcVVDSVBjdGYwVDIyRWwwUGY4YTo2d19NQm9xYnBFXzRLNHR0Wkc0NXhxd0NMTDRh"  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=6d1d0f8afbd147d24bcd42bbc5361a1' 'https://10.108.106.214:8250/token'
```

I am referring to the documentation in the URL 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Token+API#TokenAPI-RenewingaccesstokensRenewing

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-20) specification, grant_type client_credentials should not issue refresh token.

> [4.4.3.  Access Token Response](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-20#section-4.4.3)
>
> If the access token request is valid and authorized, the authorization
> server issues an access token as described in Section 5.1. **A refresh
> token SHOULD NOT be included.**

You have to use [Password Grant Type](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=47515507)

Request :

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin" -H "Authorization: Basic bkxidjNPTnYxQ25iTXBRY2E3V3hPajdaMUVZYTpuTUQzX0tKQkhGRmxFUUlXdllmSjdTUFlleThh, Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://localhost:8243/token
```

Response :

```
{"scope":"default","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3247,"refresh_token":"91729a78a96b58d80d869f3ec2ce8b8","access_token":"ec54b39dd9503c9f65df84b67ea586"}
```

Use the `refresh_token` to [Renewing access tokens](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Token+API#TokenAPI-RenewingaccesstokensRenewing)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: How we can create Java code through HttpClient or Resttemplates? Could you please help? Or How to use POstman or RestTemplates Thanks, Neha

Comment: java client for what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, in the response you have received.

```
"scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":1094,"access_token":"6d1d0f8afbd147d24bcd42bbc5361a1"
```

This is the new access token.

```
access_token":"6d1d0f8afbd147d24bcd42bbc5361a1"
```

Take note of the current token, then run the curl command again. The response should be a different token.